# Can we make the JVM to throw our own user defined exception?

Tags: java, exception

In java predefined Exceptions throws automatically. like,

```
int a=10, b=0;
c = a/b;
```

throws ArithmeticException

```
int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
int b = a[4];
```

throws ArrayOutOfBoundException

wherein in case of user-defined exceptions we should create an object of that Exception class and throw it manually.Can I make my own Exception to behave like the above two cases?

Comment: Like where? In what situation would you have your exception be thrown? Examples are really useful.

Comment: This would probably break more code than it is useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I make my own Exception to behave like the above two cases?

No, it would have to be built into the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

You may, but you have to catch the original and then throw your own.

```
try {
    int a=10, b=0;
    int c=a/b;
catch (Exception e){
    //disregard exception, throw your own
    throw new MyCustomException("My Custom Message");
}
```

Or, if you have a condition where you want to throw an exception on a case where an exception wouldn't normally exist, you just throw it!

```
// In this case, only move forward if a < b
int a = 10, b = 0;
if (a >= b)
    throw new MustBeLessThanException("a must be less than b!");
```

Or something silly like that.

Be sure to make the custom class extend Exception or one of the subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

No, all you can do is catch and then throw your own:

```
try {
    int a=10, b=0;
    c = a/b;
} catch (ArithmetikException e) {
    throw MyException("Bad!", e); // pass in e to getr a meaningful stacktrace
}
```

But I really wouldn't recommend that (except in cases where you have to, ie. when implementing an interface that doesn't declare an exception that might be thrown in your code). But then again, your example both are RuntimeExceptions (which are unchecked) and those don't have to be declared.